# jsoup class name spaces，jcoup1.8.1 can‘t use document..select("div[class='a b c']")

Tags: jsoup

```
String html = "<div class='a b c'>helloworld</div>" + 
              "<div class='b a c'>thanks</div>"; 
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.select("div[class='a b c']");
```

has no effect， I want to get the first div，what should I do?

thanks！

Comment: have errors：String html = "<div class='a b c'>helloworld</div>"
    + "<div class='b a c'>thanks</div>";

Comment: What do you mean "no effect"? You have to do something with the result. You can print it - `System.out.println(doc.select("div[class='a b c']"));` and see the div, or assign it's text to some variable - `String s = doc.select("div[class='a b c']").text();

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup ignore the space. You have to try like this to get First `div`.

```
 String html = "<div class='a b c'> helloworld</div>    <div class='b a c'>thanks</div>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);  
    System.out.println(doc.select("div:eq(0)")); 
   //if  you need plain text you can use like below
   System.out.println(doc.select("div:eq(0)").text());
```

Comment: it is effective